# How to properly set up a KVM bridge?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, netplan

I had a big problem, no matter how I set up the bridge for KVM, the network constantly drops until I return everything as it was. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so I'm turning to you. I tried setting up a netplan using similar guides: https://linuxhint.com/install-kvm-ubuntu-22-04/

Here is my yaml:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
          on-link: true
    enp12s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
```

Here is what I tried last time:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    enp12s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      interfaces: [eno0]
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
          on-link: true
```

I do not know what other information to provide, but I am ready to give any

Comment: The comment on the head of your yaml file says "NetworkManager", but the "renderer" is "networkd". This does not fit together.

Comment: I updated this server so it used network manager, but I switched to netplan. Just forgot to remove this comment in yaml

Comment: Netplan only tells the real "renderer" what to do. in your case it tells "networkd" what to do.

Comment: I don't understand what I need to fix. Well, I understood for sure that this is the renderer line, but what should I enter there then?

Comment: If your renderer is "NetworkManager", then set it in the "renderer" line ... or directly configure it in NetworkManager config. Again: netplan is only giving a hint to the real network renderer. If the real network renderer has a config, netplan config is ignored.